# Cumsum table with missing value

Tags: r, cumsum

```
dt <- data.table(Name =c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"), 
             Number = c(1,3,3,4, 4, 1,1,5,8))
```

I created cumsum table in this way.

```
library(matrixStats)
tbl <- round(prop.table(table(dt), 1) * 100, 3)
tbl[] <- rowCumsums(tbl)
names(dimnames(tbl)) <- NULL
tbl[] <-  paste0(sub("^([^.]+)(\\.[^0]).*", "\\1\\2", tbl), "%")
cumsumtable <-  as.data.frame.matrix(tbl)
```

In original dt, 2,6 and 7 were missing so it didn't reflect the table.

[image]

My desired cumsum table is like this. 2,6 and 7 are filled with the percentage before.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert the 'Number' to `factor` column with `levels` specified

```
dt[, Number := factor(Number, levels = min(Number):max(Number))]
```

and then running the OP's code

```
cumsumtable
#   1   2   3    4    5    6    7    8
#A 25% 25% 75% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100%
#B 40% 40% 40%  60%  80%  80%  80% 100%
```

---

This can also be done via data.table methods after the column conversion to `factor`

```
dcast(dt[, .N,.(Name, Number)][, perc := 100*N/sum(N), Name], 
     Name ~ Number, value.var = 'perc', fill = 0, drop = FALSE)[,
      (2:9) := lapply(Reduce(`+`, .SD, accumulate = TRUE),
              function(x) paste0(x, "%")), .SDcols = -1][]
#  Name   1   2   3    4    5    6    7    8
#1:    A 25% 25% 75% 100% 100% 100% 100% 100%
#2:    B 40% 40% 40%  60%  80%  80%  80% 100%
```